# Select id based on todays date

Tags: php, mysql

I got a table named `stats_eu` that stores `id, acc_name` and `date`. I would like to select `id` based on `acc_name` and `date`. The `date` in the database is stored like this: 2015-05-16 13:35:19 (datetime)

This is what I have tried that didn't work:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `stats_eu` WHERE `acc_name`='".$name."' AND `date`='".date('Y-m-d')."'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo "name: " . $name . "<br />";
echo "id: " . $row['id'] . "<br />";
```

That code just prints the `name` but not the `id`. Could someone please point our my error?

Comment: It is likely that your script does not print an `id` because your SQL query does not return a single result. `$name` is printed because that's a variable with a value assigned somewhere earlier in your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql `Date()` function converts string or datetime into date.Just use this query

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `stats_eu` WHERE `acc_name`='".$name."' AND Date(`date`)=Date(NOW())" );
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked but I have a question regarding `NOW()`. If the server is using UTC as timezone, will `NOW()` also use it?

Comment: actually yes it will use server time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `stats_eu` WHERE `acc_name`='".$name."' AND `date` LIKE '".date('Y-m-d')."%'");
```

I added LIKE operator in your query...